# data_from_left = text_box_left.lower().split(keyword.replace('"',''))[1]

Tags: javascript, java, python-2.7

I am new to python and javascript. I have a prebuilt python scraper that uses this script that is designed to search for name and address. It uses a keyword such as "to:" and the text following would be "to: name + address".
But this script has an index problem that is list index out of range.

I am not sure that this is the right script, but I am trying to fix this.
I would appreciate any comments and suggestions.
Thank you !
This is the text area that relates to text_box_left.

u'Recorded in Official Reco...0.00 AND WHEN RECORDED MAIL'

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8vds7lgcqxe2uwp/AADDBsV96bpKuBztn19xdCJ7a?dl=0

Comment: if this link does not work or any questions let me know....thx

Comment: when i run this code with keywork of "to:", it runs ok without fail. but when keyword is "to:" "dissolution" or otherwise two keywords...it fails!!!

Comment: this is the statement that is has index exceeding the bounds

Comment: data_from_left = text_box_left.lower().split(keyword.replace('"',''))[1]

Comment: data_from_left = text_box_left.lower().split(keyword.replace('"',''))[1]